# Why won't resharper find my unit tests?

Tags: nunit, visual-studio-2012, resharper

For some reason when I open a new solution Resharper always refuses to find unit tests. I spend half an hour struggeling/rebuilding/poking until suddenly Resharper magically finds my unit tests. Once they are found it runs them fine every time.

Test example:

```
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace NamespaceOfTheCodeToTest.Test
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class FunctionalityTest
    {
        [Test]
        public void Scenario_Input_Result()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I am using RESHARPER->Unit Tests->Run All Tests from Solution

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: So where has it been migrated too?

Comment: Are you using any fancy NUnit features like `TestCaseSourceAttribute` or `ValuesAttribute`? Do you have custom NUnit addins?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was NUnit test adapter was not installed. After installing that visual studio extension all tests where found instantly.

Edit: a better solution is to use "Run Unit Tests" on the test project, folder with test projects or solution.